# SQL: exclude rows that are duplicates according to some column arrangement

Tags: sql, duplicates, filtering, rows

In my problem, I have these rows e.g.:

```
    id1  |name1| id2 | name2| c 
1   10994,Apple,22265,Banana,103
2   22265,Banana,10994,Apple,103
3   20945,Coconut,20391,Date,101
4   20391,Date,20945,Coconut,101
```

They show pair-wise combinations of ids and names, together with another column *c*.

I consider row 1+2, and 3+4 as duplicates, considering the pairings of ids and names. Rows 1+2, or 3+4 show basically the same information.

I had no luck removing the duplicates with grouping, because id1 + id2, or name1 + name2 respectively are distinct columns.

Can I add something to my SQL query that removes these 'duplicates', so that only rows 1+3 are output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach here would to be aggregate by the `c` column and then use a least/greatest trick to tease apart the duplicates.  Here is a general solution which should work on any version of SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c, CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id1 ELSE id2 END AS id1,
                   CASE WHEN id1 < id2 THEN id2 ELSE id1 END AS id2,
                   CASE WHEN name1 < name2 THEN name1 ELSE name2 END AS name1,
                   CASE WHEN name1 < name2 THEN name2 ELSE name1 END AS name2
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c77fd1ec388c59219bd2aa3fac15c12f).

Note that on databases which have a `LEAST` and `GREATEST` function, the above can be simplified to:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT c, LEAST(id1, id2) AS id1,
                   GREATEST(id1, id2) AS id2,
                   LEAST(name1, name2) AS name1,
                   GREATEST(name1, name2) AS name2
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Does this also work when 'c' is not unique? Because it isn´t here, maybe I should have made that more clear in my example. C can be any integer number, and its values can appear an arbitrary amount of times

Comment: @PandaPhi Please check the demo to better understand how my answer works.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me understand it, and it works. I thought (upper version) I could make it faster, because here it is equivalent to also compare the id's in the third and fourth 'case when' statement instead. However, despite my expectations (ints instead of strings compared), this doesn´t make the query faster at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using *not exists*. You have not provided any existing query but something like:

```
select *
from Tablename t
where not exists (
  select * from Tablename t2
  where t2.id2 = t.id1
);
```